# I have a problem with Selenium NoSuchElementException (Python)

Tags: python, selenium

I have problem with Selenium. I catch `NoSuchElementException` because the page may have not finished loading. I have problem when page loading finished. It doesn't work as intended.

Python code:

```
onclickbtn = False
while (True):
    if onclickbtn == False:
        try:
            browser.find_element_by_class_name('btn.btn-solid-primary.btn--l.btn-solid-primary--disabled._3Kiuzg')
            print('Btn Close')
            browser.refresh()
            # sleep(0.5)
        except NoSuchElementException as exc:
            # print(exc)
            print("NoSuchElementException")
        except:
            browser.find_element_by_class_name('btn.btn-solid-primary.btn--l._3Kiuzg').click()
            print('Btn Open')
            onclickbtn = True
```

code HTML 1

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-solid-primary btn--l _3Kiuzg">Click</button>
```

execute 1

```
NoSuchElementException
NoSuchElementException
NoSuchElementException
NoSuchElementException
...
...
...

as exc
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".btn.btn-solid-primary.btn--l.btn-solid-primary--disabled._3Kiuzg"}
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.114)
```

code HTML 2

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-solid-primary btn--l btn-solid-primary--disabled _3Kiuzg">Click</button>
```

execute 2 (it work but take as a comparison)

```
Btn Close
Btn Close
Btn Close
NoSuchElementException
NoSuchElementException
NoSuchElementException
Btn Close

as exc
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".btn.btn-solid-primary.btn--l.btn-solid-primary--disabled._3Kiuzg"}
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.114)
```

help me figure out how to fix it.

Comment: so for both the case button has `Click` text on it right ?

Answer (score 0):

find_element_by_class_name need an argument to be merely the name of the class not div or . or something else.

Try browser.find_element_by_css_selector('btn.btn-solid-primary.btn--l.btn-solid-primary--disabled._3Kiuzg')

```
'btn.btn-solid-primary.btn--l.btn-solid-primary--disabled._3Kiuzg'
```

This is a css selector, not a class name.

Comment: find_element_by_css_selector don't work, but thx